# How can I test if Object has value by key without ignoring TypeScript warning: 'string' can't be used to index type?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a simple function that looks like this

```
const options = {
  option1: "option1",
  option2: "option2",
  option3: "option3",
} as const;

function getOption(str: string) {
  if (options[str]) {
    /**
     * Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ readonly option1: "option1"; readonly option2: "option2"; readonly option3: "option3"; }'.
     * No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ readonly option1: "option1"; readonly option2: "option2"; readonly option3: "option3"; }'.ts(7053)
     */
    return options[str];
  }

  return "defaultOption";
}
```

Now, I know I can solve it like this

```
const options = {
  option1: "option1",
  option2: "option2",
  option3: "option3",
} as const;

function getOption(str: keyof typeof options) {
  if (options[str]) {
    // Solved! No warning!
    return options[str];
  }

  return "defaultOption";
}
```

But it seems like I'm **lying** to my code...

For example, if I write something like this

```
function isArray(arg: any[]) {
  return Array.isArray(arg);
}
```

It will be weird to use this util because these two reasons

1. If I know it's array before runtime, I don't need to use this util at all
2. If I don't know if it's an array before runtime then TypeScript will yell again!

And here is another example:

Suppose I want to get the `'defaultOption'` by passing argument `null`, it will be so **weird**

```
// TypeScript yells!
// Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type '"option1" | "option2" | "option3"'.ts(2345)
console.log(getOption(null));
// => 'defaultOption'
```

I will have to do this to suppress the warning

```
// No more warning.
// Making null as any is weird
getOption(null as any);
// => 'defaultOption'
```

As you can see, I have to explicitly convert the `null` as `any` in order to get my `'defaultOption'`

Is there any way I can improve my `getOption` util?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want to type `getOption`'s argument to be a key of the options, to require callers to pass a sensible argument. But if you want to permit any argument may be passed to `getOption`, including a key, or a generic string, or any value at all like `null`, then type the argument as `unknown`, then have TS narrow down whether the argument is one of `options` keys:

```
function getOption(str: unknown) {
    if (str === 'option1' || str === 'option2' || str === 'option3') {
        return options[str];
    }
    return "defaultOption";
}
```

Comment: You could also use a type guard function to be less repetitive, but it'd require a notable amount of code, so you might prefer to just write out every possible value unless there were a whole lot of keys

Comment: `const keys: unknown[] = Object.keys(options); const isKey = (arg: unknown): arg is keyof typeof options => keys.includes(arg);` then use `return isKey(str) ? options[str] : "defaultOption";` The ugly `unknown` is needed is because of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255